# Shuddering between 60 and 70 kmph: 2008 Fiat Panda

Tags: abs, shaking, fiat

Car is shuddering between (roughly) 60 and 70 kmph, not below or above. Doesn't seem to matter what gear.

In one instance during a 15 minute drive ABS light came on and it seemed to shudder more violently at every speed but the next time driving the car it returned to the previous state.

Any suggestions as to what it may be?

Comment: I think we need to clarify if this is a shuddering, which may be a engine issue (fuel delivery, etc.), or a vibration which may be a rotating part issue (snow in wheel, driveshaft, etc.)

Comment: In addition to answers below, you should check your front end components: tie rod ends, ball joints, etc. Depending on your mileage these will also cause shuddering at higher speeds.

Answer (score 1):

A shuddering at a particular speed is usually a balance issue - the fact that it happens in any gear suggests wheels or tyres - most likely, you have loast a wheel balance weight. I'd suggest getting your wheels balanced (which any tyre shop will do for a nominal fee)

Answer (score 0):

If ABS light came on, there could be an issue with your brakes.

Brakes could cause shuttering if the rotors are very warped or cracked.

But typically shuttering at a given vehicle speed not engine speed is something to do with the wheel or tire. Could be alignment too if something in the suspention is bent, less likely though.

If it is the wheel it's a thrown balance weight.

If it's the tire, internal steel belt may be broken, nail(s) in tire(s), or heavy local wear on one side of the tire (from bad alignment).